# Linux Mint fails to boot if unable to mount (shared) device listed in fstab

Tags: linux-mint, windows, fstab, automounting

I have a dual-booted system of Mint and Win7, both of which share an external drive storing non-essential files. I listed the drive in `/etc/fstab/`

```
UUID=693E145023EB681E /media/External_HDD ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

so it would auto-mount on boot in Mint. If the drive is not explicitly given an drive letter in Windows (i.e. mounted), then Linux will boot without error. However, if I have the drive mounted in Windows then mounting it during boot on Linux will fail, which has the effect of halting and hanging the boot sequence.

So, the procedure I currently follow to successfully boot Linux is to first ensure the drive letter is removed in Windows.

- Why does the boot fail in Linux if a rule listed in `/etc/fstab/` mounts unsuccessfully?
- Is there a way to ensure the drive is shared harmoniously between Mint and Win7?

Comment: ntfs-3g probably returns error back to boot script or like because Windows did not "finished" (unmounted) the drive. Drive then is not "clean", and ntfs-3g fixes it, possibly with error code.

Comment: It's also a bad practice to leave drives in mounted state after OS shutdown or hibernation, because if you will make any changes to it offline from it's host OS, the OS after return will see it in same state as before and can corrupt it. Regardless of OS type.